При редиректе выходит url c названием порта, как его убрать?
При редиректе выходит url c названием порта https://tehno-bar.ru:80/catalog/, как его убрать?
Таким образом прописываю редирект в битрикс 1с
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://tehno-bar.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

Попробуйте так
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^:]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{1}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

